# Cross Domain Policy iFrame - inspecting for elements?

Tags: jquery, iframe

just curious if it's possible to inspect an iFrame with src set to some other website for it's elements?

for instance checking with jQuery if the iFrame contains a `<div class="hello">`

is that possible?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, no.

It would be a security hole if you could even look at the contents of another site (on which the user might have sensitive information!). You want to find out if a page has a certain div on it, you'll have to fetch that page from your server (which means no user credentials) and look. You can do it from the client using XMLHttpRequest to your server acting as a proxy if you like.